# Configure encryption of data at rest in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, encryption, cluster-computing

I have built a 3 node MongoDB 3.2.3 Cluster on RHEL 7.

As encryption is a new feature in this version of MongoDB I have tried enabling it different ways in my config file. Below is a part of my config file:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.

security:
 authorization: enabled
 keyFile: /data/mongodb-keyfile/auth-keyfile

encryption:
 enabled: true
 Keyfile: /data/encryp-keyfile
```

Trying to enable encryption using local keyfile .

When I am trying restart the service with the above configuration, the encryption configuration service is getting terminated.

Can someone guide me how to enable encryption for data at rest in MongoDB?

Comment: the above issue is because due to very low swap memory size .

Comment: As swap memory size increased the issue was resolved and now my cluster is running with encryption .

Answer (score 0):

- Add the above configuration.
- Delete the Dbpath folder and create the same with proper permissions.
- Restart the mongod again.